# How to use multiple parameters in query router

Tags: go, filter, routes, gorilla

everybody!
The question is:
How to write  multiple parameters in query router, so I can write one, two or more parameters like this:

```
  /applications/filter/?date=today
  /applications/filter/?status=true
  /applications/filter/?date=today&status=true
```

I tried this, but it does not work for single parameter, only for two:

```
router.HandleFunc("/applications/filter/", authMiddle.RequiresLogin(authContrl.FilterDateStatus())).
        Queries("date", "{date}", "status", "{status}").Methods("GET")
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#registered-urls) states that:
"All variables defined in the route are required, and their values must conform to the corresponding patterns."
Accordingly, you will probably have to register the routes multiple times to match each case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit confusing in the beginning, but your route is always the same here:

```
  /applications/filter/?date=today
  /applications/filter/?status=true
  /applications/filter/?date=today&status=true
```

It is always `/applications/filter/`.

In that case you just need to map one route here. The handle func receives the [request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request). Inside the request you can [parse the url](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ParseQuery).

https://play.golang.org/p/op49nTJSlCP

Putting all together it could look like:

```
router.HandleFunc("/applications/filter/",func(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
    // in production you should handle the errors!
    // I am just skipping this to keep the example simple
    u, _ := url.Parse(r.URL)
    v := u.Query()
    if _,ok := v[date]; ok {
        // do something with dae
    }
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me:  cannot use r.URL (type *url.URL) as type string in argument to url.Parse